# How to find, remove and read text in this symbol ${}

Tags: groovy

Sample data key in by user.

1. booking/${mm}/${yyyy}
2. ${yyyy}/booking/${mm}
3. booking/${mm}${yyyy}/00

My problem is how to take out ${ } and read what contain in there and then replace by month/year depend on format.

So the output should be "booking/10/2013" after save into database.

Im using Grails. Hope can solve this problem using Java / groovy.

Comment: Just literally `String#replace(String, String)` it?

Comment: what i mean is that is how user key-in some field.

Answer (score 0):

i just solve the problem`enter code here`

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String bookingNo1 = "booking/${mm}/${yyyy}";
    String bookingNo2 = "${yyyy}/booking/${mm}";
    String bookingNo3 = "booking/${mm}${yyyy}/00";
    String newDate = null;
    newDate = getDataString(bookingNo1);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    newDate = getDataString(bookingNo2);
    System.out.println(newDate);
    newDate = getDataString(bookingNo3);
    System.out.println(newDate);
}

public static String getTimeString(String pattern) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat();
    format.applyPattern(pattern);
    return format.format(new Date());
}

public static String getDataString(String dateInput) {
    String dateString = dateInput;

    String regex = "\\$\\{(mm|yyyy|DD|MM)\\}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(dateInput);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String datePattern = matcher.group()
                .replaceAll("(\\$|\\{|\\})", "");
        dateString = dateString.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + datePattern + "\\}",
                getTimeString(datePattern));
    }
    return dateString;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Groovy:

```
// Given these inputs
def inputs = [ 'booking/${mm}/${yyyy}',
               '${yyyy}/booking/${mm}',
               'booking/${mm}${yyyy}/00' ]

// Make a binding for 'mm' and 'yyyy'
def date = new Date()
def binding = [ mm   : date.format( 'MM' ),
                yyyy : date.format( 'yyyy' ) ]

// Then process each input with STE and print it out
inputs.each { input ->
    println new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
                           .createTemplate( input )
                           .make( binding )
}
```

That prints:

```
booking/10/2013
2013/booking/10
booking/102013/00
```